# Why is the \bye command not used by LaTeX?

Tags: macros, compiling, tex-core, plain-tex, latex-misc

Is there a technical reason why the `\bye` TeX command was replaced in LaTeX by `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`?

I suspect there must be a good technical reason behind this, as otherwise it would be just window dressing. I cannot imagine otherwise replacing a 4 character command placed at the end of the document with two separate commands, one 16 characters, and the other a 14 character command, having to be placed at the beginning and end.

Comment: `\bye` and `\end{document}` do completely different things, and environments are the main syntactic construct introduced by latex, so why do you find this strange?

Comment: Also what syntax would you have used for `\begin{document}`? Something close to `\bye` is available in latex namely `\stop` but it should never be used in normal documents, it's useful in some test cases and error trapping code.

Comment: There would be no problem in making `\bye` to do the same as `\end{document}` and adding, say, `\start` to do the functions of `\begin{document}`. But I can't see the problem; the number of characters is clearly a very minor aspect.

Comment: @egreg I suspect that even you would manage `\def\bye{\end{document}}`  :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're forgetting `\outer`. `:-P`

Comment: Totally honored to have both of you commenting on my question.  I've arrived.

Comment: @AFeldman: egreg comments on basically question (and answer) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I did notice that. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's look at how `\enddocument` is defined (see `latex.ltx`, the LaTeX "kernel"):

```
\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage
   \begingroup
     \if@filesw
       \immediate\closeout\@mainaux
       \let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo
       \let\@newl@bel\@testdef
       \@tempswafalse
       \makeatletter \@@input\jobname.aux
     \fi
     \@dofilelist
     \ifdim \font@submax >\fontsubfuzz\relax
       \@font@warning{Size substitutions with differences\MessageBreak
                  up to \font@submax\space have occurred.\@gobbletwo}%
     \fi
     \@defaultsubs
     \@refundefined
     \if@filesw
       \ifx \@multiplelabels \relax
         \if@tempswa
           \@latex@warning@no@line{Label(s) may have changed.
               Rerun to get cross-references right}%
         \fi
       \else
         \@multiplelabels
       \fi
     \fi
   \endgroup
   \deadcycles\z@\@@end}
```

A full discussion of what all is being executed would be very tedious. Among the more interesting activities, in my view..., are (a) the `\clearpage` instruction, which flushes all pending floats, (b) the closing of the `aux` file, and (c) a check if some cross-references are still unresolved; if there are still-unresolved references, the following famous warning message about needing to rerun LaTeX is generated:

```
           \@latex@warning@no@line{Label(s) may have changed.
               Rerun to get cross-references right}%
```

---

The definition of `\bye` (see p. 357 of the Texbook) follows a completely different model:

```
\outer\def\bye{\par\vfill\supereject\end}
```

---

Finally, here's the definition of `\stop`, a macro mentioned in a comment by David Carlisle:

```
\def\stop{\clearpage\deadcycles\z@\let\par\@@par\@@end}
```

(`\@@end` is a LaTeX-internal version of the "primitive" command `\end`.) Can you tell why David added that "it should never be used in normal [LaTeX] documents"?

Comment: I guess it should not be used because all your references would be off, as well as other not so good things would happen. Good answer.  I looked for a `\def\begindocument` line in the kernel and didn't find it.  Is there a similar function defined for `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @AFeldman - Thanks. Look for `\document`, lines ca 1619 to 1668 of the current version of `latex.ltx`. :-)

Comment: I don't see `\bye` as "completely different model". (a) All inserts are flushed by `\end` primitive too and `\dosupereject` mcro does a little more. (b) all opened files are closed automatically when TeX ends. (c) is .aux specific and plain TeX does not provide .aux.

Comment: @wipet - I suppose I'm guilty of not having explained how I use the term 'model'. Certainly not in some very rigorous sense. If the word model troubles you, I'm OK rewriting the sentence. Please advise.

Comment: *Can you tell why David added...?*  No.  Can you explain what is wrong with the `\stop` macro?

Comment: @user1717828 - `\stop` only performs `\clearpage` (which is done early by `\enddocument`) and `\deadcycles\z@\@@end` (the very last few instructions performed by `\enddocument`). That's why David C. wrote that `\stop` may be suitable for "some test cases and error trapping code" -- but not for normal documents which, almost certainly, need to do write to and read back from the aux file.

Comment: @AFeldman the macro `\begin` checks whether its argument is defined, while `\end` requires an explicit `\end<something>` command, to ensure that the group is closed. So for some environments you can state `\myenv ... \endmyenv`, but that would take away the syntactic sugar of the current LaTeX environment mechanism.

Answer (score 15):

There are syntactical reasons. LaTeX has the concept of environments, not present in plain TeX. The environment `document` is the outer environment of the document contents.

The setup/configuration of the document is separated from the actual document contents and this is done in the preamble before the environment `document` starts. The preamble loads the class and packages, which is not allowed in environment`document`.

Also `\begin{document}` introduces the concept of document initialization, again not present in plain TeX. For example, the `.aux` file is read in `\begin{document}` (and again checked in `\end{document}`.

The environment form enforces proper nesting of environments:

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{quote}
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        % Compare \bye vs. \end{document} here
      \end{tabular}
    \end{quote}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If `\bye` is the normal form of ending a document, then it can be written inside other environments in a syntactically correct appearance, see the previous code. But the wrong place becomes obvious, when written as `\end{document}`.

Comment: I guess I am sincerely confused.  I thought that Plain Tex has environments using `\def\begin` and `\def\end`

Comment: Plain TeX does not have environments. `\begin` is not defined and `\end` is a low level primitive command for ending the TeX job (LaTeX saves and internally uses it as  `\@@end`).

Comment: So a \begingroup  \endgroup  in Plain Tex is not declaring the beginning and end of an environment.  I'm struggling with that idea.

Comment: `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is a different concept. They start and end a group, where assignments are local. Environments are more, definable code at the begin and end (even with arguments for the begin part), extended syntax checking, ...

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me. I think that I have a ways to go before I really understand the distinction.  But that is not the fault of your explanation, more that I need to learn more before the explanation makes sense to me.