# Why does LaTeX throw an error without \begin{document}?

Tags: tex-core, format-files

Consider the following "Hello, World!" document.

```
Hello, world!
\end
```

If you try to compile this using `latex.exe`, you get the error**

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Okay, so on one hand, it should be obvious that one would get this error---this is a bit like trying to compile a C program without a `main` function.  On the other hand, if I am thinking of LaTeX as just TeX with a bunch of macros loaded, one would think that any document that would compile fine using `tex.exe` should work just as well without `latex.exe`, at least so long as I'm not using any macros specific to Plain TeX.***

This suggests that my understanding of LaTeX as being effectively equivalent to TeX but with an `\input{latex}` command at the beginning of the document is incorrect, which thus raises a couple of related questions.

1. My understanding was that loading a TeX format is essentially equivalent to `\input`ing a file at the beginning of the document, except perhaps that the file has been precompiled.  Is this understanding inaccurate?
2. Is a call to `latex.exe` actually equivalent to a call to `tex.exe` with the LaTeX format loaded?
3. If in fact running `latex.exe` is equivalent to just running TeX with the LaTeX format, then how does this format tell TeX to throw an error if it doesn't see a `\begin{document}`?

** Incidentally, you also get an error related to the fact that `\end` means something different in LaTeX.  I also find this confusing because I didn't think you could redefine TeX primitives, but perhaps this is better saved for a separate question.

*** Actually, I'm not even sure if there are macros specific to Plain TeX that LaTeX doesn't also define.

Comment: latex.ltx : `LaTeX must be made using an initex with no format preloaded` so the answer to the 1 and 2 is  no.

Comment: again latex.ltx : `\everypar{\@nodocument} %% To get an error if text appears before the` where `\@nodocument` is error message. and `\document`  redefine `\@nodocument` to `\relax`

Comment: @touhami it may _say_ that but it's only a computer program, it can be tricked:-)  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91042/is-there-any-software-that-converts-latex-file-to-tex-file/91050#91050

Comment: From your question it is not obvious if you want to know the motivation for LaTeX doing this, or how LaTeX technically implements this.

Comment: @chtz Originally I was curious to know how it technically implements this, but I suppose if there is nonobvious motivation for designing it this way, I would also be curious to know.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303911/why-is-the-bye-command-not-used-by-latex

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> 1. My understanding was that loading a TeX format is essentially equivalent to `\input`ing a file at the beginning of the document,
>      except perhaps that the file has been precompiled.  Is this
>      understanding inaccurate?

More or less true, although you need to interpret that with some care.

> 2. Is a call to `latex.exe` actually equivalent to a call to `tex.exe` with the LaTeX format loaded?

yes but crucially without the plain format being loaded (what was originally called virtex) and ignoring the point that hyphenation patterns can only be loaded in initex, not in a normal run.

> 3. If in fact running `latex.exe` is equivalent to just running TeX with the LaTeX format, then how does this format tell TeX to throw an
>      error if it doesn't see a `\begin{document}`?

`latex.ltx` sets

```
 \everypar{\@nodocument} %% To
```

so every paragraph generates an error, `\begin{document}` clears this and allows paragraphs to be set.

> ** Incidentally, you also get an error related to the fact that `\end` means something different in LaTeX.  I also find this confusing
>   because I didn't think you could redefine TeX primitives, but perhaps
>   this is better saved for a separate question.

yes of course you can redefine any primitive

```
\def\hbox{oops}
```

will redefine `\hbox` (not a good idea but ...)

> *** Actually, I'm not even sure if there are macros specific to Plain TeX that LaTeX doesn't also define.

yes there are macros defined in plain not defined in latex (`\folio` for example) and many many commands that are defined with the same name in both formats have different definitions (`\loop` for example).